# Excel MDX - Count of dates selected in slicer

Tags: excel, mdx, olap, olap-cube

I'm using Excel to connect to an OLAP cube and building a report to show actual hours charged to a project. I need to create a measure now to perform some calculation on the actual hours for which I need to get the number of days that the user is filtering on. The date range is added as a slicer. Is there a way to do this? I've tried

Count(Existing [Work Item].[System_CreatedDate].members)

But this returns all created dates in the entire data set. I only need a count of the ones the user has filtered on. Right now it should return 66 or so since I've set it to 1/1/2014 to 3/7/2014 but I'm getting back 503 which is how many members there are in total in the OLAP cube not taking into account any filters I have set.

My apologies for the basic question and the inadequate explanation of what I'm trying to get to. I have very limited experience with MDX and measures / members. I hope the question is clear enough.

Help will be truly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure about MDX but in excel you have to look at `xlVisible` property to get filtered results.  Something like this: `CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlVisible)`

Comment: Thanks @PortlandRunner but unfortunately this has to be done in MDX. Getting the count is only piece of the puzzle and I need to combine values from other measures and perform calculations on this count to get a final value to display.

Comment: Could you perhaps use [Excel cube functions](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/cube-functions-reference-HA010342384.aspx) to get that number and then do the rest of the calculations in Excel?

Comment: Otherwise, where are you using that calculation in your queries? You should be able to have a calculated measure for this that is filtered by the selections you choose in your slicer.